# Why is viewDidAppear: called while unwinding?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have several view controllers, which present each other using segues, and all cover the full screen (none of them are popovers). When the top one unwinds to one further down (i.e. segue A > B > C > D, then D unwinds to A), the ones in the middle run their `viewDidAppear(_:)` functions. Currently, I'm using `viewDidAppear(_:)` to kick off network requests to load data, but I don't want to do this in that case. `isBeingDismissed` and `isMovingFromParent` are `false`, so I can't use that to detect this.

Is there a better function to use for this than `viewDidAppear(_:)`? If not, how can I detect that a controller is in the middle of an unwind like this?

Answer (score 0):

You just have the test backwards, that's all. Do the loading only if `isBeingPresented` or `isMovingToParent` is *true*.

Comment: I still want to call the function if view controller D unwinds to B, but not if it skips over B and unwinds straight to A. It sounds like this solution wouldn't call it for either unwind.

Comment: In that case I'd avoid unwind and do something over which you have actual control.

Comment: It seems like even calling the `dismiss(animated:completion:)` function on view controller B triggers its `viewDidAppear(_:)` to be called, with `isBeingDismissed` as `false`. Interestingly though, view controller C has `isBeingDismissed` set to `true`.

Comment: Another possibility might be to not worry about all this stuff and just add another event: cancel the data load in `didDisappear`. So you might start but you'd immediately stop. No point loading data if there's no time for user to see it.

Comment: How did you define the unwind ? I defined a similar configuration, with an unwind func in VCA. When I exit from VC D, I go directly to VCA, not transitioning through others.  And viewDidAppear is not called even for A, unless transitions are full screen.

Comment: @claude31 All the view controllers are full-screen. I'll edit my question to say that.

Comment: If you make them "automatic", problem should completely disappear. Otherwise, you may get an error such as "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UnwindTests.ViewControllerB"